# Add/remove checkbox values to/from array when checked and unchecked (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox

On a project I'm currently working on, I'm using radio buttons and AJAX to change the posts displayed on a custom WordPress template page. It works perfectly, however, the client would like it to be checkboxes instead of radio inputs so that each time a user selected a new category, it adds to the posts being displayed instead of replacing it.

For example: currently, if you click category1, category1 posts show up. Click category2, and category2 posts replace the category1 posts. The client would like BOTH category1 and category2 to show up if both checkboxes are selected.

Here's my JS currently:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // AJAX Post Filter scripts
  var $checkbox = $("#filter input:checkbox");
  var $checked = $("#filter input:checkbox:checked");
  var $unchecked = $("#filter input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
  $checkbox.change(function () {
    if ($checked) {
      var catID = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
        data: {
          "action": "load-filter",
          category__in: catID
        },
        success: function (response) {
          $(".filter-section").empty().html(response);
          return false;
          console.log('success!');
        }
      });
      console.log(catID);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm pretty sure I need to do something with `.map()` with my variable `catID` as I've seen in some other threads, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works quite right for me.

edit: I realized I needed to clarify what I *have* tried.

I've used the following code:

```
var catID = $(this).map(function () {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

But all it does is replace the variable value with the new checkbox value. I need to add to the value without erasing the already checked values. Then if a checkbox is unchecked, I need to remove the value from the array.

Comment: you probably don't need to use map, you're gonna have to reapproach how you're rendering the ajax result. I would change `catID` from a single value to an array of values. Add an onclick handler for the checkboxes, and do two things 1) if the ID is in the array, remove it, if it isn't in the array add it 2) `.forEach()` id get the filter data and use `.append()` instead of `.html()` to add it to the page. That's not exact but I would start there, that's the approach I would take.

Comment: Which result set would need to be displayed first? would they just need to be appended one after the other? would it make sense to just pass in an array of selected id's to your endpoint and have your endpoint do the work instead?

Comment: Robbie, could you possibly give me a snippet as an example?

Comment: Kevin, it doesn't matter which is displayed first as long as they both display. I have to admit I'm not sure what you mean by your suggestion, though.

Comment: You can't store a collection of `:checked` before your `change`. The original collection won't be altered as a result of the change. Also `if(jQuery Object)` will always be truthy... use `length` of it to determine if it has elements or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
let categoryIDs = [];

$('.checkbox').click((e) => {
  let id = e.currentTarget.id

  $(selector).html('')
  categoryIDs.indexOf(id) === - 1 ? (
    categoryIDs.push(Number(id))
  ) : (
    categoryIDs = categoryIDs.filter((item) => item !== id )
  )

  console.log(categoryIDs)
  categoryIDs.forEach((item) => {
    //ajax calls here

    //$.ajax({blah blah}).done(res => {
      //$(selector).append(res)
      //})
    console.log(item);
  })
})
```

See it in action here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mwypd9ve/

This way the IDs you want to display are always in the array, and every time the array changes the page will reflect only the content matching the IDs in the array (because you clear the section `.html('')` then in the loop append each ajax response

Comment: It's returning NaN in the console log for both `categoryIDs` and `item`

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I needed to use `value` instead of `id`. My new current problem is that I need to remove the value from the array when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: just use filter and `.indexOf()` like I did in my example. Is there a particular part you don't understand? I'm happy to answer any questions

Comment: Well it works perfectly, but when I uncheck a box, it just adds the value to the array (again) instead of removing it. It seems to do the same in your example. So I'm trying to figure out now how to remove the value when I uncheck a checkbox.

Comment: Oops that is my fault check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/mwypd9ve/2/ if you are curious, the reason is because my code was checking if `"1" === 1` for example, which is never true. By converting the id to a number immediately I mitigate this issue, now the code checks if `1 === 1` for example. The line in question is `let id = e.currentTarget.id` which I changed to `let id = Number(e.currentTarget.id)`